# Get FieldType and Cast String As

Tags: apex

I have a list of ***sObjectsToInsert*** which will be inserted at the end of a set of scripts.  It will contain many different sObjectTypes, so it must be built dynamically (get/put).

One problem I'm running into is when a field type is a non-string, yet I'm passing a string value through via ***values.get(value)***

```
public void addToInsert(sObject so, Map<String, String> values) {
    for (String value : values.keySet()) {
        so.put(value, values.get(value));
    }
    sObjectsToInsert.add(so);
}
```

How can I cast ***values.get(value)*** as the ***value*** field type dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `Map<String, String> values` to `Map<String, Object> values` and no casting should be needed.

It is also normally better to use `SObjectField` as the type of the key in this sort of map.

Be careful about the ordering of the different types in the list: Google "Updating Records for Different Object Types" to read about "chunks".

Comment: `Map<SObjectField, Object>` is definitely better.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!  I read up on "chunks" and that would appear to be a problem down the line with the max of 10 chunks.  My thinking is that I can re-order by sObjectType just before commit, but thanks for pointing out this potential issue!

Comment: Yeah the sort by sObjectType is the way to go if the "add" order is indeterminate...

Comment: What if you're getting field values as Strings from a parsed CSV and need to cast from Strings to match the sObject fields' data types?  Just a bunch of if-elses (until Apex gets switch statements) with type checks and [DataType].valueOf() calls or casts?

Comment: @BrentBow Yes if the data values are of the wrong type you will have to do explicit type conversion.